# How to light LEDs with Arduino without having any resistors

Tags: arduino, led, resistors

I've got a silly situation. I have an Arduino board (2009). There's just one inbuilt LED but can't do much with it beyond blinking. I have five LEDs (3 yellow, 2 green), breadboards, jumper wires but not resistors. (And there is a total lockdown here) I wish to play with these LEDs but can't risk it putting it directly. I tried using them in series but that did not light them up.
I know each LED needs a 330ohm resistor but that I don't have. I even have a 2x 7 segment display too but the same problem.

Any way to use them?
Thanks.

Update:

On suggestions, we have got two resistors from a faulty solder gun (blue-grey-orange-gold = 68k) and a (brown-black-brown-gold = 100) and 1 IN4000 diode.

Comment: What else do you have that has resistance? Potentiometers?

Comment: Use PWM. AVR timer has CTC mode of operation. Using it you can implement PWM in any register/bit. I don't know much about Arduino. But they have libraries for using any feature of AVR.

Comment: Don't have them.

Comment: PWM will reduce RMS value.

Comment: PWM will still drive too much instantaneous current. Both the MCU and the LED will have their ratings exceeded, so no, do not use PWM.

Comment: @SadatRafi RMS values are useful for linear devices. LEDs are inherently non-linear, and will experience large, damaging currents during the on-portion of each PWM cycle, no current during the off-portion, and will not be saved by the fact that the RMS voltage is low enough

Comment: AVR has built-in resistors. It didn't come up in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as the loop function of your Arduino sketch:

```
void loop() {
pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); //Pull up is built in to the Atmega chip. 
//It will be at least 20k - very little current will flow through the LED.
// LED should light dimly.
//May need to turn off room lights or cover with hands to see.

delay(1000);  // Wait one second.
pinMode(2, INPUT); //Input mode turns off the pull up.  No current to LED.

delay(1000);  
}
```

Connect an LED to GPIO 2 (or use another pin and change the code to match) with the LED cathode connected to the Arduino ground.

It may be **very** dim.  The built in pull up will be at least 20k, and may be as high as 200k depending on which processor is built in to your Arduino.

[Information on "pinMode".](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/pinmode/)

[Information on Arduino pull ups.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins)

---

The above is a trick, and may not work.  I haven't tried it out.

Whether it works or not will depend on how efficient your LEDs are and which processor you use.

Try it out.  It **cannot** hurt your processor or your LED.

Do **not** change the pin mode to output.  That may damage your processor (though probably not.)

---

This is the [same idea that Sadat Rafi had](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/511945/47070) except using the Arduino library functions rather than generic Atmega code.

The same cautions about LED efficiency that I've given here apply to that answer as well.

---

Pin 13 was a poor choice on my part.  It is used for other things on the Arduino.

I've changed the code to use GPIO 2, which shouldn't have any conflict.

Do **NOT** use GPIO 0, 1, or 13 with this trick.

Those pins are connected to other things on the Arduino board.  Those other things could cause damage to the Arduino if there are LEDs attached, and will almost certainly interfere with normal operation of the Arduino.

Comment: It worked! Though when sketch writes the code to the chip, my yellow LED gives two full bright blinks. And then plays the loop in dim blinks.

Comment: Changed to GPIO 2.

Comment: Last question, which all pins support this trick? Can I use all of 2-13?

Comment: All except 13.  As you've noticed,13 is connected to an LED and is used to signal progress while the code is being flashed into the processor.  I shouldn't have used in the example when I first wrote, but it slipped my mind the GPIO 13 is different.

Comment: Also GPIO 0 and GPIO 1, but most Arduino users avoid those anyway - they are used for programming the Arduino flash.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JRE

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    SFIOR &=~ (0<<PUD);
    PORTC |= 0x01;

    while(1)
    {
    DDRC ^= (1<<0);
    _delay_ms(10);
    }
}
```

AVR microcontroller has a built-in 10K resistor with every output pins. Arduino should have libraries related to it. They are called pull up resistors. I checked it using the code I provided.
[image]
This screenshot is taken from the AVR datasheet. You can see that there is a Resistor inside that can be operated by switching the internal MOSFET.

So, ask in the Arduino forum about the library associated to it.

Comment: This might work, but those LEDs had better be efficient. The pull-up equivalent resistance is between 20k to 50k. That doesn't provide very much current, resulting in very dim LED light.

Comment: Since it's Arduino, why don't you use digitalWrite and pinMode?

Comment: I've heard that ATMEGA series has 10k. I searched in the datasheet but didn't find the value.

Comment: digitalWrite() function doesn't use pull up. Arduino is simply a huge collection of libraries. If you need to use pull up then you will need to find the function associated to it. The code I provided will be inside that built-in function.

Comment: Thanks @SadatRafi the pull up trick worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for you, but no, there's no way of connecting LED's to Arduino without resistors, without risk of damages to your Arduino's ports or the whole chip itself.

Even if you try to connect them in series of 2 (2.5V per LED) or 3 LED (1.6 v per LED), it is not advisable.

Don't you have a broken electronic device that you could scavenge for resistors? Even a burnt CFL or LED lamp can have some resistors that you could use. 330 ohm is just a **minimum** value, but as you want only an initial learning experience with Arduino, LED's values from 330 ohm to even 10k ohm can permit Arduino to light a LED safely.

CFL lamps have diodes, you could connect a series of 4 diodes to make a 2.4/2.6 V reductor, this series of diodes could permit using a lower value resistor (CFL lamps usually has a low value resistor, under 100 ohm).

What are the LED's colours? Their voltage depends on colour.

Comment: 3 yellow and 2 green LEDs

Comment: This [link](https://makecode.adafruit.com/learnsystem/pins-tutorial/devices/make-a-resistor) would change your quarantine's Arduino play in an emergency resistor building task. Once a time I saw a guy online telling about his father, that was from the resistence in WWII, used this method to build resistors for his radio transmitters.

Comment: A generic yellow LED, a generic green LED, and a single diode from a burn CFL could work, too.

Comment: Great idea. We have ~6 clamps to use and lot of pencils.

Comment: To be honest: the idea seemed better than really is. I've just did some tests here. I connected directly to the graphite leads, and resistance is too low (about 20 ohms). I tried a hatched stripe in paper, I barely lighted a red led using a small distance of only 2mm.

Comment: Thanks @mguima. We have HB pencils only. will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have higher valued resistors, try those.  I've had up to 20K series resistance with a red LED (high luminosity, admittedly) and it was still clearly visible in office/lab lighting.  You can go for more intensity later, but this may be sufficiently visible for bench debug.  How high you can go on resistance is probably different for each device, and I've tried this with exactly one sample, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Anything between about 250 ohms and 10K will work fine. Surely you can sacrifice something and pull resistors out of it and maybe extend the leads a bit.

Answer (score -4):

In case a 5V VCC if you dont want any resistors you can connect 2 leds of voltage drop of 2.7V in series. One of the LED's wont be completely forward biased and will limit current.

Comment: How do you know what voltage drop LEDs the OP has? If they are red LEDs, two of them in series will burn with overcurrent. If they are blue or white, two of them will never even light up.

Comment: And if the LEDs were the same type they would have the same voltage drop at the same series current.

Comment: One LED will shine and the other wont and we have limited current without resistors.

Comment: @HelenaWells Sorry, that isn't quite right. If the LEDs are in series, they have the same current and thus the same number of charge carriers crossing the junction, hence both must light up. You're still likely to have very poor current regulation: no light if the voltage drop is too high, and LED damage if it is too low.

Comment: Wait a minute but one will be forward biased even with low current.

Comment: LED'S dont light if they are not completely forward biased .

Comment: @HelenaWells Both will be forward biased but not enough to make them light up - probably. It *might* work.

Comment: I've just tried this now: picked two white leds from the same batch, both of then 2.65V when connected with a properly chosen resistor (I measured). I connected the two LEDs in series, directly to the power supply. At 4.0 V, one of them were very dim at 2.4V and the another one was completely off at 1.6V (both both were from the same batch). I rised the voltage; at about 4.5v the second LED start to turn on, dimly. At 5V both of them were dim, the voltage across each LED were 2.5V, and they're conducting 0.8 mA. @Helena Wells' idea could work, if the total serie LEDs voltage is barely above 5V

Comment: I changed the LEDs and I didnt' get to repeat the first observation; with other pairs, only one of the LED's lights up (dim) at full 2.65V and about 1mA, and the second LED doesn't lit, and stays at 2.4V.

Comment: Connecting LEDs, or diodes in general, directly to a voltage source without a negative current feedback (in ther simplest case: a resistor) is a very bad idea. Diodes have very steep voltage-current-curves and even the slightest increase in voltage can cause a tremendous increase in current and damage the diodes. For the same reason it is not a good idea either to put diodes in parallel.

Comment: The OP asks how to connect LEDs without a resistor.